# Vb.Net Properties Syntax

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have asked my colleagues at work and even tried to look up this on the internet but I haven't been able to get an answer.

What is the difference between

```
Public Property Name As String
```

and

```
Public Property Name() As String
```

What difference makes adding () after the property name?

Comment: No difference. Furthermore, Visual Studio will add the parentheses for you. It just makes the syntax more uniform.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - actually VS doesn't add these parentheses automatically it just doesn't require them (they are optional)

Comment: @MattWilko Hmm. Maybe it used to? It’s been > 5 years since I last worked with VS. Of course it’s also possible that I remember wrongly, since VS is/was automatically adding parentheses in other places.

Comment: I think you are thinking about Subs/Functions for which it does add them ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you may find it that Property has many similarities to Methods. 
from this prospective, parenthesis in Property used for parameters. if a Property has no parameter you can omit it. following is the full property declaration syntax:

```
[Default] [Modifiers] Property PropertyName[(ParameterList)] [As DataType]
[AccessLevel] Get
    ' Statements of the Get procedure.
    ' The following statement returns an expression as the property's value.
    Return Expression
End Get
[AccessLevel] Set[(ByVal NewValue As DataType)]
    ' Statements of the Set procedure.
    ' The following statement assigns newvalue as the property's value.
    LValue = NewValue
End Set
End Property
```

You may find valuable tips in following links:
[What is the difference between a parameterized property and function in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728321/what-is-the-difference-between-a-parameterized-property-and-function-in-vb-net)
AND 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8ae41a4.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You lookup these kind of details in the [VB.NET Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15039).  It is a pretty formal document but nevertheless quite readable.  Chapter 9.7 contains all the details about the Property keyword syntax.  You'll for example see:

```
PropertySignature  ::=
    Property  Identifier  [  OpenParenthesis  [  ParameterList  ]  CloseParenthesis  ]
        [  As  [  Attributes  ]  TypeName  ]
```

The [] brackets indicate optional parts of the syntax.  So you can easily see that you don't *have* to use () if the property doesn't take any parameters.  In other words, when it is not an indexed property.

So there is no difference.

Comment: That’s the wrong way of reading the spec: `[…]` indicates that the part is optional, but it does *not* indicate that it has no effect. In fact, other parts in `[…]` in your example above *do* have an effect.

Comment: Erm, I only said "optional parts of the syntax".  I avoided saying anything at all about effects.  The language spec is good for that.

Comment: “I avoided saying anything at all about effects” — then what is “so there is no difference”?

Comment: @KonradRudolph "if the property doesn't take any parameters" then "there is no difference"

Comment: @mbomb007 Sure, but the part of the specs quoted here definitely doesn’t say this. It merely indicates that both constructs (with and without parentheses) are legal constructs. It does *not* guarantee that they have the same effect. In fact, there is a situation where this exact difference occurs: Inside an invocation expression, parameters can be specified either as the variable name (`foo`) or as a parenthesised variable name (`(foo)`). Both are legal, but have a *different* effect (parentheses force `ByVal` passing).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Nothing of what you just said is relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @mbomb007 And nothing that Hans has said is relevant to OP’s question, **for the same reason**. That’s my whole point. Hans’ answer merely proves that both syntaxes are legal. Not that they have the same effect. My comment merely illustrates, via an analogous situation, why Hans’ argument is fallacious.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Having parameters is NOT an analogous situation to not having them. His argument is flawless; yours is the opposite.

Comment: @mbomb007 My argument isn’t about having vs not having parameters, it’s merely about the existence of parentheses. — But let’s forget this and do something different: Let’s assume, purely for argument’s sake, that there *is* a difference between (parameterless) properties with and without parameters. How would Hans’ quoted spec section look then? Would it look different? — The answer is no: it would look the same. There would however be a note *elsewhere* specifying the difference.

Answer (score -1):

According to the online language reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/property-statement), the parens are required:

```
Property name ( [ parameterlist ] )
```

though as we know they can be omitted with no change to the meaning, if there are no parameters.

However there's an important difference when referencing the property. If you have an overloaded property and an overload with parameters references one without, the parens are mandatory on the call to the parameterless overload otherwise it resolves as a call to self which returns nothing.

I.e. in the following code, there is an "uninitialized" warning on line 17: `Return MyProp.ToUpper()` and it generates a null reference exception at runtime.

If you add parens to the two "recursive" calls, i.e. `MyProp()`, it works as expected.

```
Class Class1

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim c As New Class1
    Console.WriteLine(c.MyProp(upper:=True))
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    MyProp = "lower"
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property MyProp As String

Public ReadOnly Property MyProp(upper As Boolean) As String
    Get
        If upper Then
            Return MyProp.ToUpper()
        Else
            Return MyProp
        End If
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```