# Parenthesis in properties in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm going over some legacy code at work and I'm wondering what is the difference between these two properties:

`Public Property HasUsedCopies() As Boolean`

`Public Property HasUsedCopies As Boolean`

Using a VB.NET to C# code converter, they come out to be the same:

`public bool HasUsedCopies { get; set; }`

What does the parenthesis denote?

Comment: I believe they're identical. VB is forgiving and if function or property don't have any parameters supplied - parentheses can be omitted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29514247/1070452

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into the [Visual Basic Language Specification under section 9.7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711977%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): Properties:

```
PropertyMemberDeclaration ::=
   [ Attributes ] [ PropertyModifier+ ] Property Identifier
      [ ( [ ParameterList ] ) ] [ As TypeName ] [ ImplementsClause ]
      LineTerminator
   [ PropertyAccessorDeclaration+ ]
   [ End Property LineTerminator ]
PropertyModifier ::= ProcedureModifier | Default | ReadOnly | WriteOnly
PropertyAccessorDeclaration ::=
   PropertyGetDeclaration | 
   PropertySetDeclaration
```

Here you see that both the parameterlist as well as the enclosing in brackets is optional:

`[ ( [ ParameterList ] ) ]`

So the brackets can be omited and thus both statements are equivalent.