# Passing Argument to JavaScript Object Getter

Tags: javascript, getter

```
var URIController = {
    get href() {
        return url.location.href;
    }
}
```

I have above object structure. But `URIController.href` property depends on another object, `url`.

If the `url` is defined globally, `URIController.href` works. But I want to pass `url` object to `href` getter manually.

```
var URIController = {
    get href(url) {
        return url.location.href;
    }
}
```

Changed the getter to accept url parameter but

```
URIController.href(url)
```

throws error because href is not a function.

Is it possible to pass arguments to getter in javascript?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to pass args to a getter in any language, you'd either have to use a _"normal"_ function or introduce a dependency

Comment: @PaulS. Well... there's at least [one language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9728321/4975230) that allows it...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Getters do not require explicit invocation with parentheses and cannot therefore accept arguments. Their invocation is implicit via standard property access syntax, e.g. `URIController.href`.

From [getter documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function...
>
> - It must have exactly zero parameters

______

If you need to accept arguments, use a function instead:

```
var URIController = {
    href: function (url) {
        return url.location.href;
    }
}
```

Or using ES6 object function shorthand syntax:

```
const URIController = {
    href (url) {
        return url.location.href;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was actually a library. I just thought if I could modify getter a bit, I can help myself without replacing all properties with function calls in library. But it seems it is not possible.

Comment: @JohnBernard I know you've probably figured this out by now, but a note to others: for the 'getter' to receive the url parameter whenever used in the library, you'd have to modify each usage of the getter anyway.

Answer (score 8):

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)

> The production PropertyAssignment : get PropertyName ( ) { FunctionBody } is evaluated as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 2. Let closure be the result of **creating a new Function object as
>      specified in 13.2 with an empty parameter list** and body specified by
>      FunctionBody.

So you cannot specify a parameter list, attempting to do so will give you a syntax error

```js
var obj = {
    get href(param){}     
}
```

If you do not want to setup a normal function you could do a couple workarounds like set a property on the class instance/object that the getter would then read. Or you could use a closure upon creating your object then your getter could access it from the outer scope.

As an instance/object property

```js
var obj = {
    url:null,
    get href(){
       return this.url ? this.url.location.href : "";
    }
}

obj.url = {location:{href:"http://stackoverflow.com"}};
console.log( obj.href );
```

With an enclosure

```js
function URIController(url){
    //You could also use `Object.defineProperty` to 
    //create the getter on a existing object
    return {
       get href(){
          return url.location.href;
       }
    }
}
var obj = URIController({location:{href:"http://stackoverflow.com"}});
console.log( obj.href );
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't pass an argument to a " getter " use a " setter " rather.