# VB.Net - Using a subclass in a class

Tags: vb.net, class

Trying to convert some VBA code to VB.Net and getting hung up on some class issues. I have a main class: clsComputer. It has a subclass: clsHardDrive. Since a computer can have more than 1 hard drive, it's `Get` and `Set` properties look like this in clsComputer:

```
Private pHardDrive(8) As clsHardDrive

Public Property Get HardDrive(index As Integer) As clsHardDrive
    If pHardDrive(index) Is Nothing Then Set pHardDrive(index) = New clsHardDrive
    Set HardDrive = pHardDrive(index)
End Property
Public Property Set HardDrive(index As Integer, value As clsHardDrive)
    pHardDrive(index) = value
End Property
```

This allows me to do something like this in code:

```
objComp.HardDrive(0).Size = "500"
objComp.HardDrive(1).Size = "1000"
```

However, I don't know how to convert this to VB.Net. I tried this:

```
Property HardDrive As HDD
    Get (ByVal index As Integer)
        Return pHardDrive(index)
    End Get
    Set (ByVal index As Integer, value As HDD)          
        pHardDrive(index) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But it gives a compile error: `Property without a 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifier must provide both a 'Get' and a 'Set'. (BC30124)`

Searching that error isn't very helpful: `To correct this error make sure you include both a Get procedure and a Set procedure between the Property statement and the End Property statement.` I have both Get and Set, and I think they are properly terminated. I've also searched for examples on using one class within another, but I didn't find anything useful.

How do I get the same functionality in VB.Net that I have in VBA? EG, how do I create the instances of HardDrive so that one computer object can have many hard drive objects?

Comment: Have a look at the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8ae41a4.aspx

Comment: Doh! #2 on that page: `If the property takes parameters, follow the Property keyword with the name of the procedure, then the parameter list in parentheses.` So it should be `Property HardDrive(byval index As Integer) As HDD` and that compiles! Post this as an answer please. :)

Comment: Reckon Cody put the effort in and deserves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexed properties [still exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9728876/366904) in VB.NET, just like classic COM-based VB.

You just have the syntax wrong. Indexed properties really just a special case of a parameterized property, so the `index` is taken as a parameter for the entire property, not the individual `Get` and `Set` statements.

```
Public Class Computer

    Private m_hardDrives(8) As HDD

    Public Property HardDrive(ByVal index As Integer) As HDD
        Get
            Return m_hardDrives(index)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As HDD)
            m_hardDrives(index) = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```